# How do you push Application updates on an installed PWA application?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, polymer-3.x

My question is, Is it possible for the Users to acquire these changes without having to REINSTALL the PWA application?

I have a PWA application deployed in Production. The client already installed the deployed PWA application in their MOBILE devices and I want to DEPLOY another patch of updates in the PWA application in the HTTP server.

Comment: Normally with a PWA, the site's cache gets loaded (for speed), and updates are loaded in the background to be shown to the user on their next visit.  So if you use the app (for more than a few seconds while changes are loaded in the background). Then close the app and use it again you should see the changes. Should be no need for a reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way to update application is using [workbox-window](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workbox-window). You can detect updates in PWA and restart your application to get the last updates. For more detail, I suggest you read [this link](https://medium.com/@webmaxru/workbox-4-implementing-refresh-to-update-version-flow-using-the-workbox-window-module-41284967e79c)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to read [this link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#updates) explaining in detail how the SW Updates work.

Long story short, if you deploy a new app version, the *new* SW will be installed on the client's side (using a separate/dedicated `install` event) and then activated when the users navigates to an URL different from the PWA one.

There is also a built in service workers feature called "fail safe". Within at most 24H the SW checks if a newer version is available and, if so, attempts to update to it.

I wrote a PWA series and here a post about [Service Workers and caching strategies](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f) if you want to read more.